# How can i protect .mp3 (audio) files from other music player's in android

Tags: android

My Goal is,

**I need to protect my audio file from other media-player apps.**

In my android media player app having the option to download the song. This audio needs to be more secure when i save in this in my internal/external storage, also this audio can only play through my app only. So i tried to encrypt my audio file and saved in .txt format. For this i used this code snippet,

**To encrypt**

```
// Buffer used to transport the bytes from one stream to another

byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    /**
     * Encrypt.
     *
     * @param in
     *            the in
     * @param out
     *            the out
     */
    public void encrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        try {
            // Bytes written to out will be encrypted
            out = new CipherOutputStream(out, ecipher);

            // Read in the cleartext bytes and write to out to encrypt
            int numRead = 0;
            while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                Log.e("encrypt - buffer - val", buf + "");
                out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

**To Decrypt**

/**
     * Decrypt.
     *
     * @param in
     *            the in
     * @param out
     *            the out
     */
    public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        try {
            // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
            in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);

            // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
            int numRead = 0;
            while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                Log.e("decrypt - buffer - val", buf + "");
                out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This code is working fine for me, may i know is any other way to acheive my goal.

Comment: Save the file in your `/data/data/your.app.name/` folder, which is private to your app.

Comment: @DerGolem: When i save my file in this location, other audio player apps can able to list my songs?

Comment: Obviously, not. But they won't also be able to list txt files. I think you have to give those files a custom extension and associate your app with that extension. So only your app will list (and decrypt) them.

Comment: Why encrypt music? This will be a slow user experience.

Comment: @JaredBurrows: absolutely valid point sir.  so only i am searching for good solution.

Comment: @DerGolem Gave you your best solution. Why are you trying to hide music?

Comment: @JaredBurrows: Because, I need to avoid the illegal use of my music. After downloading, that audio file can able to play via my app only. If i don't hide/protect, they easily hear via some music app.

Comment: @DerGolem: i created a folder as per your guidance, still my downloaded song are listed in music player.

Comment: If you added an MP3 to your internal app folder, only that app can see it. You entire question has now changed from "protecting" from other apps to basically adding a DRM to your music. Are people purchasing music in your app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73330/discussion-between-aerrow-and-jared-burrows).

Comment: @Aerrow I can't talk for very long, I am just trying to get more information about your question.

Comment: @JaredBurrows: In my app i used copyrighted musics, I need to avoid illegal and piracy of my audio files. so i moving to encryption technique, in this i encrypted the song and modified the file format. i assume, all music players are listed only .mp3 (or other mms formats)files, here i changed .txt so it can't be listed in players.

Comment: Are users are purchasing music or the app is coming with the music?

Comment: @JaredBurrows: there is no purchasing, i provide the song free of cost. Also i added two option one for preview another one is download. if the user can hear the song via preview option, if they like then download.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named as ".nomedia" in that folder where you have audio files.This will protect

Comment: Not if they use the `MediaScannerConnection` and specify the file directly? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html